# UmbracoMemberProfileProvider in version 7 does not exist, what is the replacement for this?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, profile, member

I am in the middle of upgrading from umbraco v6.0.5 to v7.2.1.

In my current(v6) web.config I have the following:

```
<profile defaultProvider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" enabled="true" inherits="NFOPP.Website.usercontrols.Security.MemberProfile, NFOPP.Website">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoProfileProvider, umbraco.providers" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <clear />
        <add name="_title" allowAnonymous="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
        <add name="_firstname" allowAnonymous="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
        <add name="_lastname" allowAnonymous="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
        <add name="_memberNumber" allowAnonymous="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

I also have a class like this:

```
public class MemberProfile : ProfileBase
    {
        #region Firstname
        private const string FIRSTNAME = "_firstname";
        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return GetCustomProperty(FIRSTNAME);
            }
            set
            {
                SetCustomProperty(FIRSTNAME, value);
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        #region Get and Set base properties

        private string GetCustomProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            var retVal = "";
            var prop = base.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                retVal = prop.ToString();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        private void SetCustomProperty(string propertyName, object value)
        {
            var prop = base[propertyName];
            if (prop != null)
            {
                base.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The purpose of this is so I can work with my MemberProfile object and access it's properties like FirstName directly.

The "umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoProfileProvider" does not seem to exist (unless I am mistaken) any more meaning I cannot seem to wire up a class that overrides the "ProfileBase" properly, and when I attempt to load a page that accesses the "MemberProfile" object it says that "No PropertyType exists with the supplied alias _firstname"

Is there a better way to do this, and in v7 is the config section actually needed any more if there is no provider?

**Solution Implemented:**

I added the following methods to my Member Profile class:

```
public static MemberProfile Get(IMemberService memberService, UmbracoContext context)
        {
            var membershipHelper = new Umbraco.Web.Security.MembershipHelper(context);

            var profileModel = membershipHelper.GetCurrentMemberProfileModel();
            if (profileModel != null)
            {
                return Get(profileModel.UserName, memberService);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static MemberProfile Get(string userName, IMemberService memberService)
        {
            var member = memberService.GetByUsername(userName);

            return new MemberProfile(member);
        }
```

I also updated the Get and Set property methods like so:

```
#region Get and Set base properties

        private string GetCustomProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            var retVal = "";
            if (_member.Properties.IndexOfKey(propertyName) > -1)
            {
                var prop = _member.Properties[propertyName];

                if (prop != null && prop.Value != null)
                {
                    retVal = prop.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        private void SetCustomProperty(string propertyName, object value)
        {
            if (_member.Properties.IndexOfKey(propertyName) > -1)
            {
                var prop = _member.Properties[propertyName];
                if (prop != null)
                {
                    prop.Value = value;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

To use this I then called the following wherever I needed the member object:

```
var member = MemberProfile.Get(ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService, Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
```

I would still appreciate any thoughts around this solution and how other people handle adding custom properties to the member and accessing them from code.

Answer (score 1):

It's by heart, but I thought you still have the asp.net based profile provider like this:

```
<profile defaultProvider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" enabled="true" inherits= "Umbarco.Models.MemberProfile, Umbarco">
```

Consider using the new [Membership API introduced in v7.1](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2014/4/3/out-now-umbraco-710)

Comment: I did end up using the new versions of the MemberService and modified my MemberProfile class with some methods to get the member based on passing the context in (I have edited my question to show what I did).
Thanks for the pointer about the new API :)